# Trouble with 'Anonymous' and 'Negotiate,NTLM' authentication in IIS7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have added the following configuration section to my web.config file

```
<security>
  <authentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
  </authentication>
</security>
```

But when I call the *.asmx web service, I still got the following error:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.

I am using the IIS7.5 ASP.NET integrated mode.

Any clues?  I just found the IIS Authenticatino is very poor and unstable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that we need to grant NTFS permission to target folder for the Anonymous Authentication Authenticated As identity, besides enable Anonymous Authentication in IIS.

Windows Authentication happens in both IIS and NTFS file system. I always forget the latter one. I will cut my dummy brain.